# ajax called onClick needs to be clicked twice only on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I made a simple ajax live search in PHP and javascript.

I used standard js ajax call script such as the one from w3schools.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

The function basically gets called onkeyup and php file returns a list of results such as the following:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onCLick='example()'>example</a>
```

The problem is that the function exampe() gets called with a single click on ie and chrome whereas on firefox, it requires a double click to call exampe() (as if the page is not focused).

Is this a known issue with firefox? Does anyone experience something similar?

Comment: have you checked for possible errors/warnings in firebug?

Comment: Can you post a link? Do the results need to be added by the ajax response to reproduce the issue? I'm not seeing the issue in this simplified case: http://jsfiddle.net/LxGfX/1/

Comment: The link is added by ajax to  span. I dont hav thelink

Comment: But it happens in every case i tried no matter what the function is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/GVbZU/ shows the code you've got above working fine, are you sure that the function you're calling as the `onclick` handler exists? Firebug (or the Firefox built in console) should give you a pointer to any errors being thrown by your JavaScript.

Instead of using the `onclick` attribute, you could event listeners attached by JavaScript instead, for example:

HTML:

```
<a id="exampleLink" href="#">example</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function example(evt) {
    // function run in the scope of the anchor element
}
document.getElementById('exampleLink').addEventListener('click', example, true);
```

Note: the example above assumes that you're not supporting IE <= 7, if you are, then you should check for the existence of addEventListener or the IE specific attachEvent instead, see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html